# Comparar elementos de la misma lista

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, app WPF. Necesito comparar elementos de una misma lista.

El escenario es el siguiente estoy obteniendo posiciones de las manos con el dispositivo Kinect el cual lo hace en tres dimensiones `X = valor`, `Y = valor`, `Z = valor`. Pero cuando se registra un movimiento esos valores cambian para eso he implementado el siguiente código, el cual siempre esta tomando datos ya que las cámaras de dispositivo son Time Of Fly.

```
foreach (var data in skeletons)
        {
            if (SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked == data.TrackingState)
            {
                Joint jointManoDerecha = data.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                Joint jointManoIzquierda = data.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];

                SkeletonPoint posicionManoDerecha = jointManoDerecha.Position;
                SkeletonPoint posicionManoIzquierda = jointManoIzquierda.Position;

                manoDerecha = string.Format("Mano derecha: X:{0:0.0} Y:{1:0.0} Z{2:0.0}", posicionManoDerecha.X, posicionManoDerecha.Y, 
                    posicionManoDerecha.Z);

                var _manoDerecha = new ManoDerecha()
                {
                    X = posicionManoDerecha.X,
                    Y = posicionManoDerecha.Y,
                    Z = posicionManoDerecha.Z
                };
                listMaDerecha.Add(_manoDerecha);

                manoIzquierda = string.Format("Mano izquierda: X:{0:0.0} Y:{1:0.0} Z{2:0.0}", posicionManoIzquierda.X, posicionManoIzquierda.Y,
                    posicionManoIzquierda.Z);

                var _manoIzquierda = new ManoIzquierda()
                {
                    X = posicionManoIzquierda.X,
                    Y = posicionManoIzquierda.Y,
                    Z = posicionManoIzquierda.Z
                };
                listMaIzquierda.Add(_manoIzquierda);

                // Dibujar huesos
                Brush brush = brushes[iSkeleton % brushes.Length];
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.Spine, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.Head));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.ShoulderCenter, JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft));
                skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(GetBodySegment(data.Joints, brush, JointType.HipCenter, JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight));

                // Dibujar articulaciones
                foreach (Joint joint in data.Joints)
                {
                    Point jointPos = GetDisplayPosition(joint);
                    var jointLine = new Line();
                    jointLine.X1 = jointPos.X - 3;
                    jointLine.X2 = jointLine.X1 + 6;
                    jointLine.Y1 = jointLine.Y2 = jointPos.Y;
                    jointLine.Stroke = _jointColors[joint.JointType];
                    jointLine.StrokeThickness = 6;
                    skeletonCanvas.Children.Add(jointLine);
                }
            }

            iSkeleton++;
        } // para cada esqueleto
```

Estoy almacenado por cada interacción del ForEach los valores de X, Y, Z en una lista.

```
public class ManoIzquierda
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Necesito comparar los valores de la misma lista una posición son los datos de X, Y, Z si se hace un movimiento las variables toman otro valor, necesito hacer una comparación.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres comparar la lista para verificar si tiene un elemento en concreto?

Comment: @Einer Necesito verificar la lista si X = 1, Y = 5, Z = -10 y los valores se mantienen iguales no se movió las manos pero si X = 1, Y = -5, Z = 8 hubo movimiento esos elementos están permanentemente tomando valores.

Comment: Osea, si cambia alguna de las propiedades de la lista, quieres saberlo. A eso te refires?

Comment: @Einer Así es a eso me refiero.

Comment: Hola, puedes establecer tu lista en una `ObservableCollection<T>` [Clase ObservableCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms668604) para notificar cuándo ha habido cambios.

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que la mejor solución para tu problema es implementar en tu clase `ManoIzquierda` el interfaz [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx). De esa manera, puedes comparar dos objetos por las 3 propiedades que tienes, y tambien usar el método `Contains` para comprobar si ya existe un objeto con las mismas propiedades en tu lista.

La implementación de tu clase quedaría asi:

```
public class ManoIzquierda:IEquatable<ManoIzquierda>
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ManoIzquierda other)
    {
        return this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y && this.Z == other.Z;
    }
}
```

Ahora, para comparar dos objetos de tipo `ManoIzquierda` puedes hacer simplemente:

```
maIzq.Equals(maIzq2)
```

Tambien como he dicho puedes usar `Contains`, así que en tu código puedes hacer:

```
var _manoIzquierda = new ManoIzquierda()
{
    X = posicionManoIzquierda.X,
    Y = posicionManoIzquierda.Y,
    Z = posicionManoIzquierda.Z
};
if (listaMaIzquierda.Contains(_manoIzquierda)
{
    //Ya existe un objeto con las mismas propiedades, no se ha producido movimiento
}
else
{
   //no existe,lo añadimos a la lista 
   listMaIzquierda.Add(_manoIzquierda);
}
```